# Calling .net framework 2 from application developed in .net framework 4

Tags: custom-component

I have an application developed using .net framework 4. I also have a DLL component developed in .net framework 2. Is it possible for me to call a component that was developed in .net framework 2? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes.  The .NET frameworks are 99% backwards compatible; very rarely are there breaking changes.  Just add the DLL to your .NET 4 project as a reference as you usually do.  If there are compile problems, post the specific errors.